# Mongo import saves all data under a single object

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I ran a mongo import command to import my json file, but all the data got saved under a single object.

```
mongoimport -d DB NAME -c COLLECTION NAME --type json --file FILE PATH --host MY MONGO LAB HOST --port 27892 -u MYUSER -p MYPASSWORD
```

But now when i see the db in mongorobot

[image]

JSON

```
 {
"-Kbr7KouYOL_a9NIAyPV" : {
"correctas" : [ 1 ],
"creator_name" : "kk",
"game_name" : "Elrubius",
"jugado" : 62,
"opciones1" : [ "Por usar una pistola falsa" ],
"opciones2" : [ "Por matar" ],
"opciones3" : [ "Por robar" ],
"opciones4" : [ "Por estar tomando alcol" ],
"preguntas" : [ "Elrubius porque fue detenido" ],
"premium" : false
},
"-Kbr8RJMSCv95m6TS4Of" : {
"correctas" : [ 2 ],
"creator_name" : "CRIATURITA",
"game_name" : "ELRUBIOSOMG",
"jugado" : 34,
"opciones1" : [ "Carlos" ],
"opciones2" : [ "Ruben" ],
"opciones3" : [ "Jorge" ],
"opciones4" : [ "Chavez" ],
"preguntas" : [ "Como se llama elrubiusomg?" ],
"premium" : false
},
```

- Is wrong to store all the data under a single object?
- How can i avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the json file i am importing? I already added it (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you combined documents into a single document.

Your formatting (indentation) hides what you're doing. But... this is what you are using, in your question (with some properties removed for brevity):

```
{
    "-Kbr7KouYOL_a9NIAyPV": {
        "creator_name": "kk",
        "game_name": "Elrubius",
        "jugado": 62,
        "premium": false
    },
    "-Kbr8RJMSCv95m6TS4Of": {
        "creator_name": "CRIATURITA",
        "game_name": "ELRUBIOSOMG",
        "jugado": 34,
        "premium": false
    }
}
```

This is just going to give you one giant document with lots of subdocuments. And eventually, you will exceed the size of a single document.

Also, the way you constructed your JSON, it's creating unique property names for each document:

- `-Kbr7KouYOL_a9NIAyPV`
- `-Kbr8RJMSCv95m6TS4Of`

I doubt that was your intent; you'll never be able to query across that, since every document has a unique property name.

You need to fix your JSON to represent several separate documents. And fix that unique id so it's queryable. Something like:

```
{
    "id": "-Kbr7KouYOL_a9NIAyPV",
    "creator_name": "kk",
    "game_name": "Elrubius",
    "jugado": 62,
    "premium": false
}
{
    "id": "-Kbr8RJMSCv95m6TS4Of",
    "creator_name": "CRIATURITA",
    "game_name": "ELRUBIOSOMG",
    "jugado": 34,
    "premium": false
}
```

You can then import this set of documents.

Note that, in my example, I added an `id` property. MongoDB creates a unique `_id` property if you don't specify one. So, if you want to override MongoDB's guaranteed-unique property, you can replace `id` with `_id` in the example above.

Comment: I know it is a bit late, but when i try to make an import with a syntax like that it throws me Failed error processing document #1 invalid character { looking for beginning of object key string

Comment: Not sure exactly why you have that issue. But you can also try wrapping all the documents in the import file in brackets: `[ {doc1}, {doc2}... ]`. Just note: I just took the exact document example in my answer and imported it via mongoimport, with no issues.

Comment: I was putting in the command the wrong file, thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

I have quickly recognized that this is a Firebase database format. What a mess ? You pay them to extract your db and this is what they give you. I am in the same shoes with you :-( I can't fix a 2 GB json file to make it compatible with Mongo.